# External SSD is recognize only with lsusb

Tags: linux, ssd, usb-storage, liveusb, lsusb

I've an external SSD with an encrypted mx-linux-19-live on it. When i boot on it, it's ok; but when i am on my installed mx-linux system, i can't mount the usb drive.
lsusb diplay it : (device 009)

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 1de1:1101 Actions Microelectronics Co. Generic Display Device (Mass storage mode)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5ab Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But nothing with lsblk, nor with fdisk -l.

I have this on /var/log/messages when i connect device :

```
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.258060] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.275262] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.277695] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.282447] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.286267] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.329418]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.373397] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV usb_modeswitch: switch device 1de1:1101 on 002/010
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19470.779806] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Dec 16 22:40:17 GeoIV kernel: [19471.017214] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Dec 16 22:40:18 GeoIV kernel: [19471.768171] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 16 22:40:18 GeoIV kernel: [19471.769149] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Dec 16 22:40:18 GeoIV mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Dec 16 22:40:18 GeoIV mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 10 was not an MTP device[/code]

I search about this error and i try to comment out this line in /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
[code]# Autoprobe vendor-specific, communication and PTP devices
ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}!="1", ENV{COLOR_MEASUREMENT_DEVICE}!="1", ENV{ID_GPHOTO}!="1", ENV{libsane_matched}!="yes", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00|02|06|ef|ff", PROGRAM="mtp-probe /sys$env{DEVPATH} $attr{busnum} $attr{devnum}", RESULT=="1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"[/code]

After reload rules (udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger), when i disconnect/connect the ssd i have this new error in /var/log/messages :
[code]Dec 16 22:44:53 GeoIV kernel: [19745.447088] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.555452] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.582809] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1de1, idProduct=1101, bcdDevice=20.01
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.582823] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.582831] usb 2-1: Product: AM8180
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.582837] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: AMicro
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.582843] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 012345679600
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.585954] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.587458] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.599435] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.600613] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.603777] scsi host0: uas
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.608805] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     AMicro   AM8180 NVME      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.620530] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.637679] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.640014] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.644638] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.648711] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.694851]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19788.751318] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV usb_modeswitch: switch device 1de1:1101 on 002/011
Dec 16 22:45:35 GeoIV kernel: [19789.176483] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Dec 16 22:45:36 GeoIV kernel: [19789.415325] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Dec 16 22:45:36 GeoIV kernel: [19790.169586] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 16 22:45:36 GeoIV kernel: [19790.170892] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
```

I tried with the  different usb port, i tried to reboot after rules.d changes, but... nothing. The drive is only visible with lsusb, but not with gparted, fdisk... I can see it in /dev/disk/by-id/ , but with a broken simlink.

Any idea about how i can reformat this drive ?

Info system:

```
System:
  Host: <filter> Kernel: 5.10.0-9-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64 
  root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel, plank wm: xfwm4 
  dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21_x64 Wildflower October 20  2021 
  base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20JNS3FG00 v: ThinkPad T470 W10DG 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20JNS3FG00 v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: N1QET69W (1.44 ) date: 12/13/2017 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 42.7 Wh condition: 42.7/47.5 Wh (90%) volts: 12.4/10.8 
  model: SANYO 01AV425 type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Full 
  cycles: 434 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-6300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Skylake family: 6 model-id: 4E (78) stepping: 3 microcode: EA 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 19999 
  Speed: 500 MHz min/max: 400/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 500 2: 500 
  3: 500 4: 500 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled 
  Type: l1tf 
  mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, 
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
  Type: tsx_async_abort mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:1916 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.5 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:9d70 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-9-amd64 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Lenovo driver: e1000e v: kernel 
  port: efa0 bus ID: 00:1f.6 chip ID: 8086:156f 
  IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: efa0 
  bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 8086:24f3 
  IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 482.68 GiB (51.8%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: PNY model: CS2130 1TB SSD size: 931.51 GiB 
  block size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
  serial: <filter> rev: CS213530 scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw size: 48.42 GiB size: 47.36 GiB (97.81%) 
  used: 13.34 GiB (28.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
  ID-2: /boot raw size: 601.0 MiB size: 574.7 MiB (95.62%) 
  used: 103.2 MiB (18.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4 
  ID-3: /home raw size: 857.93 GiB size: 843.46 GiB (98.31%) 
  used: 469.24 GiB (55.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-stable-updates.list 
  1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list 
  1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
  2: deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/leap.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list 
  1: deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_testing/ ./
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mx.list 
  1: deb http://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/mxlinux/packages/mx/repo/ bullseye main non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list 
  1: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/various.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main

Info:
  Processes: 281 Uptime: 8h 20m Memory: 7.65 GiB used: 2.14 GiB (27.9%) 
  Init: SysVinit v: 2.96 runlevel: 5 default: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.1 
  alt: 10 Shell: quick-system-in running in: quick-system-in inxi: 3.0.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This USB ID is or was used for an old Philips PicoPix projector.
WIll this work for You?

1. sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
2. changed DisableSwitching=0 to DisableSwitching=1
3. ^O (save)
4. ^X (exit)
5. reboot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, it's work, the ssd appears again ! Thanks. Could you explain what is this file (usb_modeswitch.conf), and what is this option (DisableSwitching ) ?